# How do I enable GZIP on tomcat spring mvc application in AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application construct with Spring MVC at AWS Beanstalk environment.

I was trying to enable GZIP deflate and follow this guide:
http://www.tonmoygoswami.com/2013/05/how-to-enable-gzip-on-amazon-elastic.html

I create two files inside ebextensions folder like that:
enable_mod_deflate.conf

```
# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Restrict compression to these MIME types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg

# Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
DeflateCompressionLevel 9

# Netscape 4.x has some problems.
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

myapp.config

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

And enable plugin in my pom.xml to generate

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/ebextensions</directory>
                        <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I check and in http conf is already include the files. 
I try restart httpd but nothing enable gzip.

I was using the site
http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/
to check and nothing seens to work.

My question is. Is there another thing to do to enable GZIP? Some code in spring MVC?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it *without* doing anything?  My ElasticBeanstalk machine already has mod_deflate loaded and in /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_gzip.conf has configuration for deflating.  I am using the Tomcat type ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: I tried. I think there's a configuration in web.xml file that I need to do.